# Getting a class' method with a string

Tags: python

I have a class that I want to call its methods using just strings. How do I do that?

```
class MyClass:
    def do_something():
        print 'MyClass did something'

MyClass.get_method('do_something')()
```

Comment: You can also just hold the method object in a variable, in case that makes your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    def do_something(self):
        print 'MyClass did something'

getattr(MyClass(),'do_something')()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
class MyClass:

    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print 'MyClass did something'
```

And call:

```
getattr(MyClass, 'do_something')()
```

Note the addition of `@staticmethod` to the method to ensure it can be called without a class instance.